# Come si chiamano le mele "Honey crisp" in italiano?

Tags: translation, nouns

Leggendolo in un articolo, volevo sapere il loro nome italiano, perché non sono riuscito a trovarlo né in Google translate né in Google e neanche nel dizionario Word Reference.

Comment: Farzad, ti ricordo che puoi porre le domande in inglese, se ti è più facile.

Comment: Grazie, però siccome vorrei imparare il mio italiano,  preferirei ad scrivere in italiano e tutti i suggerimenti di correzione sono benvenuti

Comment: @Farzad64: hai proprio una bella intenzione! Una piccola correzione: "preferire" è seguito dall'infinito senza preposizione, quindi "preferirei scrivere in italiano" :)

Comment: @Benedetta grazie mille Benedetta

Comment: Un'altra correzione: al posto di "imparare il mio italiano" usa "imparare l'italiano" oppure "migliorare il mio italiano". Buono studio!

Answer (score 5):

Queste? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycrisp

Non credo che abbiano un nome italiano, si usa l'inglese *Honeycrisp* come per praticamente tutte le altre varietà di mela: Royal Gala, Granny Smith, Stark Delicious...

Answer (score 0):

In Italia non modifichiamo i nomi dei prodotti che importiamo, per questo la nostra lingua è ricca di parole inglesi. L'Italiano medio distingue le mele associando il colore alla mela e raramente chiamandola per il nome proprio di appartenenza.

Answer (score 0):

Da Wikipedia:

> U.S. Plant Patent 7197 and Report 225-1992 (AD-MR-5877-B) from the Horticultural Research Center indicated that the Honeycrisp was a hybrid of the apple cultivars 'Macoun' and 'Honeygold'.[2] However, genetic fingerprinting conducted by a group of researchers in 2004, which included those who were attributed on the US plant patent, determined that neither of these cultivars is a parent of the 'Honeycrisp', but that the 'Keepsake' (another apple developed by the same University of Minnesota crossbreeding program) is one of the parents. The other parent has not been identified, but it might be a numbered selection that could have been discarded since.

Il che significa che come per tutte le cose, se sono state inventate in una certa nazione o chi le ha inventate era di una certa nazionalità o ancora se sono state brevettate in una certa nazione, bisogna chiamare le cose col nome in quella lingua di quella nazione. Esempio è Joules, cognome di origine francese di un celebre scienziato inglese. Si leggerebbe "Giul" e non "Giaul". Ci sono professori universitari di fisica che ti mandano a casa se glielo pronunci all'inglese.

Comment: Suppongo che tu ti riferisca a James Prescott **Joule** (senza contare che la pronuncia corretta, /dʒuːl/, non è né inglese né francese: è la pronuncia del nome di quella persona lì, e nemmeno di alcuni suoi omonimi).

Comment: Il discorso per quanto riguarda le mele è corretto, ma quello che dici implicherebbe che dovremmo chiamare la lampadina col suo nome inglese perché l'ha inventata (o perfezionata) Edison, dovremmo dire *Kernspaltung* in onore di Lise Meitner e Otto Hahn e così via...

Comment: si esattamente, poi trasgrediamo alla regola continuamente.

Comment: Ah, c'è una “regola”? :) Dove sta scritta?

Comment: la regola, dettata dal buon senso, vorrebbe che il termine italiano per indicare "Lasagne" rimanesse "Lasagne" anche in lingua inglese/francese/ostrogota, trasgrediamo continuamente alla regola perché come delle Capre inglesizziamo termini italiani e italianizziamo termini stranieri